# Spring and Angular JS

Tags: java, angularjs, spring, spring-mvc

I'm developing an application using Spring and angular JS . But I don't know if what I'm doing is correct or not . In the same Maven project , I made 
a user class then I created a @RestController in which I've created my webservice . In the webapp folder I created my index.html file (and an app.js) in which I used Angular JS . I runned my application on tomcat server and it works fine .

is this application  Full client side ? what I think is that Spring MVC expose my service as a REST and Angular JS consume it . Should I keep the web service in this app and make another client application using Angular JS ?? help me  , I'm lost

Answer (score 1):

Your front-end is loosely coupled with the back-end since the two sides interact only with restful services. It does not break this approach if you package both AngularJS and spring files in the same application. Separating the two applications brings some complexity which could be necessary if you need to package two deployable files (one front.war and one back.war for instance). If you don't have this concern, then you should keep things like this IMHO.