# How to configure Spring Boot with Angular JS app

Tags: javascript, angularjs, spring-boot

I am trying to learn Spring Boot and Angular JS.

1) I wrote a Spring Boot application having a REST controller to expose some rest APIs.

2) I wrote an Angular JS application on a different workspace. My app consists just of two files viz. index.html and a app.js.

Opening my index.html runs my angular JS app and communicates successfully with Spring Boot rest app.

I want to combine both projects into an executable jar to ship. Double clicking the jar should start my Spring Boot application and be ready to serve my angular js app.

I wrote spring controller as below:

```
@Controller
public class MyAppController {

@RequestMapping("/MyAppContextRoot")
String home(ModelMap model) {
    model.addAttribute("title","My App");
    return "index";
 }
}
```

However, on trying to access "http://localhost:8080/MyAppContextRoot" is not working.

What am I doing wrong ?

Does it have to do something with ng-route? My understanding is, since my application is index.html itself, I do not need ng-route and things should automatically work.

Am I wrong? Can someone please explain.

Comment: Show your console output, e.g. the error

Comment: No error on console. I get this when I hit context root: Whitelabel Error Page

Comment: What is the http status, it is 200 or 404 or 500? What is `Whitelabel Error Page`, nothing on it?

Comment: The http status is 404.. There was an unexpected error (type=Not Found, status=404).... My index.html is placed below src/main/resources/static directory

Comment: Do you specified the `context-path`, may be you URL some thing like `http://localhost:8080/app/MyAppContextRoot`

Comment: I have a yml file which has: ---
server:
  port: 8080
  contextPath: /MyAppContextRoot

Comment: So you URL must be `http://localhost:8080/MyAppContextRoot/MyAppContextRoot`, check it

Comment: I did it.. still the same result. I changed the path at top of controller to "/" and tried "http://localhost:8080/MyAppCotextRoot/"... still the same result.. 404 error

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Spring and Angular JS](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29064504/spring-and-angular-js)